# How to link correctly apple iOS library?

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, dlopen

Under delphi Tokyo, If you look for example `iOSapi.MapKit.pas` you can see that the initialization section is fired only if `NOT defined(CPUARM)` (basically the initialization section is run only for iOS Simulator):

```
{$IF defined(IOS) and NOT defined(CPUARM)}

initialization

MapKitModule := dlopen(MarshaledAString(libMapKit), RTLD_LAZY);

finalization

dlclose(MapKitModule);
{$ENDIF IOS}
```

But when you see `iOSapi.CoreTelephony.pas` it's not the case :

```
initialization
  CoreTelephonyModule := dlopen(MarshaledAString(libCoreTelephony), RTLD_LAZY);

finalization
  dlclose(CoreTelephonyModule);

end.
```

Any idea why ? Today i face a strange bug, I implement the `PHPhotoLibrary` (Photos Framework) in the same way they do with `iOSapi.MapKit.pas`, so doing

```
{$IF defined(IOS) and NOT defined(CPUARM)}

initialization

PhotosModule := dlopen(MarshaledAString(libPhotos), RTLD_LAZY);

finalization

dlclose(PhotosModule);

{$ENDIF IOS}
```

and it's work in my ipad Pro but **not** on iphone 7 where i have the error :

> ObjectiveC class PHPhotoLibrary could not be found

when i execute `TPHPhotoLibrary.OCClass.authorizationStatus`

removing `{$IF defined(IOS) and NOT defined(CPUARM)}` make the code working correctly on Iphone 7. So what is the rule to follow to link correctly apple Ios library (Library from the apple framework) ? always using dlopen or not ?

Comment: I've implemented the photos framework (conditionals are the same as yours) and never had this problem, however I do not have an iPhone 7 to test on. What version of iOS is on it?

Comment: @DaveNottage: on iphone 5 with ios 9.3.5 it's crash and on ios 12.0 it's crash also, same for ios 11.4 ... most crazy is that on some ios it's not crash !

Comment: Might help to show exactly what code crashes, including a call stack

Comment: @DaveNottage it's simply raise ObjectiveC class PHPhotoLibrary could not be found exception when calling TPHPhotoLibrary.OCClass.authorizationStatus

Comment: Do you have a "loader" method declared, similar to this? {$IF Defined(CPUARM)}
procedure libPhotosLoader; cdecl; external libPhotos;
{$ENDIF}

Comment: @DaveNottage: no ...